# Rotativa - How to fit div's width with pdf page's width

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-to-pdf, rotativa

I have a HTML document like this:
[image]

My problem is: When I use rotativa to export this HTML document to PDF, the body doesn't resize automatically to correspond with the PDF's page size. For example, when I choose A5 size and portrait, the content doesn't zoom out, so a part of the body is cut off.

What I want: Export this document to PDF and it should be able to auto resize to correspond with the PDF's page size and orientation. I mean it should zoom in or zoom out to fit 100% width of page size. Moreover, It should looks like how it appears on the browser exactly. Please note that my body must has fixed size because all inside elements have absolute position.